# The independence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, markov-chains

Here is my question:

*Consider a homogeneous ergodic Markov chain on a finite state space $X=\{1,\ldots,r\} $. Define the random variables $\tau_n \,,n\ge1$ as the consecutive times when the Markov chain is in state 1, that is
$\tau_1 = \inf(i\ge0 : w_i=1) $, $\tau_n = \inf(i > \tau_{n-1} : w_i =1)\,,n>1$. Prove that 
$\tau_1\,,\tau_2-\tau_1\,,\tau_3-\tau_2\,,\ldots $ are independent random variables.*

Notice that "homogeneous Markov chain" means that the transition matrix are time independent. $w_i$ stands for the state of the Markov chain at step $i$.

Comment: A proof by induction based on the strong Markov property at time $\tau_n$ seems direct, no? Additionally, $(\tau_{i+1}-\tau_i)_{i\geqslant1}$ is i.i.d.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think a proof by induction will work. By the way, what's the definition of strong Markov property?